# Updating json via bot command

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a command (<MF_add) that adds a point to member's json value and that only admins can use.
This is my code right now:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def MF_add(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    with open ("MF Points.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)   
        
        await client.get_user(user_id)
        user = client.get_user(user_id)
        if user in users:
            users["{user.mention}"]["points"] += 1
            await ctx.message.channel.send(f"You have given {member.mention} 1 MF point.")
                
    with open("MF Points.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f, indent = 4)
```

It's not giving any errors, but it's also completely unresponsive.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is the await message send actually sending?

Comment: No, nothing happens when I try the bot in Discord

Comment: i think you forgot to add `bot.command()`

Comment: Oops! No, it was there. Just inputted wrong into my post.

Comment: try using `if user in users.items():`

Comment: No, that didn't do anything and didn't give an error either. I do use if user in users: earlier in the code in order to make an input for when members join and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First off I'd like to recommend you use SQLLite instead of JSON. JSON is not a database. You should really refrain from using it to store user data that can frequently change.

Regarding what you've currently got, JSON is used similar to a dictionary. It uses keys and values. I highly doubt that the if statement `if user in users:` is returning true. You should check (with a print statement) to see if the if statement is even working.

Comment: It should be true as he seems have a dictionary loaded within it, so it looks for the key (it wont work for multiple other reasons though)

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually make a command here, the `@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)` is not what you use to make a new command. You need a `@bot.command()` in front of it like:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(administrator=True)
async def MF_add(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    with open ("MF Points.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)   
        
        await client.get_user(user_id)
        user = client.get_user(user_id)
        if user in users:
            users["{user.mention}"]["points"] += 1
            await ctx.message.channel.send(f"You have given {member.mention} 1 MF point.")
                
    with open("MF Points.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f, indent = 4)
```

That would solve your question I believe, now to talk a bit about your program as it will not function like you expect it to, at all (or it'll just error):

- client.get_user(userid) is not asyncronous and doesn't need to be awaited
- you seem to never define user_id anywhere (as it is a variable)
- why do you want to get the user again in the first place? You get the user from you parameters right?
- `["{user.mention}"]` from when you look at the user's key is nothing but a string, you need to add an f in front of it for it to actually look for a mention value in user
- ctx.message.channel.send can be shortened to ctx.send
- f"You have given {member.mention} 1 MF point." You never defined a member value

I've rewritten most of your code into something that should work I believe:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(administrator=True)
async def MF_add(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    with open ("MF Points.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)   
        
    if str(user.id) in users:
        users[str(user.id)] += 1

    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = 1
    
    await ctx.send(f"You have given {user.mention} 1 MF point.")
                
    with open("MF Points.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f, indent = 4)
```

Note that not knowing what you actually want to achieve with this code/what other functions you want to introduce I'm not too sure this is the best way. But you should be able to figure things out with this as a basis

Note: I converted the keys to strings as json doesnt like int keys, you can use int keys if you use a custom object_hook though (I'll let you look into that, it probs isnt work looking into for the use case you have anyways)

Comment: Thank you so much for this in-depth answer! I actually had @client.command written at the top but the post formatting got wonky. I tried your new code and still nothing. There's gotta be something in the if statement.

Comment: @beepbeepboop try temporarily saving your MF Points file somewhere else and just having a new MP Points file with just an empty dictionary in it. Then try the command again, see if that does anything. (the last version i sent)

Comment: Just tried clearing the json and still nothing. I AM getting the print though because of the indentation, so that's all good. Just something before that.